# Is there a big (if any) performance difference between Geoserver SQL Layer and OpenLayers geojson Layer?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, geojson, sql-server

I have a table with multiline geography items in SQL Server 2008 (Routes).
I want to show them on OL Google Map but I'm having trouble creating SQL Data source in geoserver (something related to TCP/IP although its opened and enabled in SQL Config).
As a workaround , I've create a web service which brings GeoJSON from the SQL and add it as a layer.

My question is , How "bad" performance wise is my solution if I want to show couple of routes that each is made from around 7k points ?

Comment: The main difference will be in time taken to load the GeoJSON. A WMS service from Geoserver, will additionally feel lighter when panning and zooming the map.

Comment: Thank you.
So I must make the SQL Data store work ...
How I can solve this.

Comment: Also consider the overhead on the browser side, I believe loading 14k points in Openlayers still incurs in significant memory overhead on the client side (but may be wrong, things are evolving and we start seeing full vector clients around that can load lots of geometries/large geometries, just believe OL might not be there yet)